# In Gradle, how do you perform validation of lazily evaluated properties (on extensions)?

Tags: gradle, properties, lazy-evaluation

Is there a way to validate a property value when the property is evaluated? I can't do it in the getter because that returns the Property object - I want the validation to run only when the actual value is calculated (i.e. I want to be lazy evaluation friendly).

They show extensions using the Property object here:

- https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/lazy_configuration.html#connecting_properties_together

However, they don't explain how to do property validation when the value is calculated. Here is the snipet of code from the Gradle documentation provided example:

```
// A project extension
class MessageExtension {
    // A configurable greeting
    final Property<String> greeting

    @javax.inject.Inject
    MessageExtension(ObjectFactory objects) {
        greeting = objects.property(String)
    }
}
```

If I wanted to make sure the value of `greeting` was not equal to `test`, then how would I do that when it is evaluated?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For most use cases, it should be sufficient to just validate the property value once you resolve it in your task or in other internal parts of your plugin. Only a few extensions are actually designed to be consumed by other plugins or the build script.

Gradle does not provide some validation that can be attached to a property, however you can build this functionality on your own like in the example below:

```java
class MessageExtension {

    private final Property<String> _greeting

    final Provider<String> greeting

    @javax.inject.Inject
    MessageExtension(ObjectFactory objects) {
        _greeting = objects.property(String)
        greeting = _greeting.map { value ->
            if (value.equals('test'))
                throw new RuntimeException('Invalid greeting')
            return value
        }
    }

    def setGreeting(String value) {
        _greeting.set(value)
    }

    def setGreeting(Provider<String> value) {
        _greeting.set(value)
    }
}

project.extensions.create('message', MessageExtension)

message {
    greeting = 'test'
}

println message.greeting.get()
```

I turned the `Property` into a backing field for a `Provider` that runs the validation when resolved. If you do not want to throw an exception, but just return an empty `Provider`, you may replace the `map` with a `flatMap`.